# Error when deploying SharePoint feature: The specified list does not exists

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, javascript, css, feature-activation

I'm using SharePoint 2010 Foundation and Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate. I'm working on a Web Parts with two features:

1. Feature1 - My Web Parts
2. Feature2 - Contains two Visual Studio module with CSS and JavaScript and jQuery code.

When I deploy my Solution by Visual Studio I have this error:

> Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Failed to instantiate file "path1/path2/picture1.png" from module "MyModule": The specified list does not exist.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

[Edit - 1]

Hi. This is my element.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module Name="MyModule" Url="CssScripts/Css">
    <File Path="MyModule\path1\path2\Picture1.png" Url="path1/path2/Picture1.png" Type="GhostableInLibrary" />
    <File Path="MyModule\path1\path2\Picture2.png" Url="path1/path2/Picture2.png" Type="GhostableInLibrary" />
    <File Path="MyModule\path1\path2\Picture3.png" Url="path1/path2/Picture3.png" Type="GhostableInLibrary" />
     ...
</Module>
</Elements>
```

Comment: The problem seems to be in your Elements.xml file of MyModule.. Please add that in your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure the document library "DbShopCssScripts" exists.path1,path2 should not be present inside the url, unleass you want it to be deployed inside path1 folder in the site (ie DbShopCssScripts/Css/path1).

Below is link msdn article ablout uploading file from solution to document library.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231567.aspx

Comment: The name of library is "DbShopCssScripts1" but the description is "DbShopCssScripts". Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Can you give me any articles that explains this, please?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not deploying to a library your should change "GhostableInLibrary" to "Ghostable". If you are in fact deploying to a library, make sure the specified subfolders do exist

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module Name="MyModule" Url="DbShopCssScripts/Css">
    <File Path="Picture1.png" Url="Picture1.png" Type="GhostableInLibrary" />
    <File Path="Picture2.png" Url="Picture2.png" Type="GhostableInLibrary" />
    <File Path="Picture3.png" Url="Picture3.png" Type="GhostableInLibrary" />
     ...
</Module>
</Elements>
```

The above should work

**Explanation**

When you define the Url in `<Module>` element, you don't need to define it again in `<File>` element, unless you want it deployed in Sub-Folder to the path defined in `<Module>` element

Comment: Hi Arsalan, can you give some reference link/article to this concept..